# Visual Studio for Mac UI bug

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, ide, visual-studio-mac

I have a visual bug in my Visual Studio for Mac: an info line at the top of UI. Does anyone had the same issue with VS for Mac and is there any way to fix this? You can see this info line at screenshots below 
[image: Screenshot with bug]
[image]

Comment: I would report this with IDE logs (Help - Open Log Directory) on the Visual Studio for Mac developer community so it gets into the bug tracking system - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html

Comment: Reported also there, if someone will be interested, here's the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232622/visual-studio-for-mac-ui-bug.html